# Associating Adjacent Elements with Perl's Web::Scraper

Tags: perl, web-scraping

The following is the example at hand :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper;

my $html = q[
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <div class="when">February 20, 2014</div>
      <div class="name">Name 1</div>
      <div class="desc">Desc 1</div>
      <div class="when">February 21, 2014</div>
      <div class="name">Name 2</div>
      <div class="desc">Desc 2</div>
      <div class="name">Name 3</div>
      <div class="desc">Desc 3</div>
      <div class="when">February 22, 2014</div>
      <div class="name">Name 4</div>
      <div class="desc">Desc 4</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
];

my $scraper = scraper {
    process ".when", "events[]" => scraper {
      my $when = $_->content();
      my $hash = {};
      $hash->{$when}->{name} = "NAME";
      $hash->{$when}->{desc} = "DESC";
      return $hash;
    };
};

my $result = $scraper->scrape($html);

print Dumper( $result );
```

What I am trying to do is associate the dates with the events details. As you can see, the divs are not nested so it is not as trivial (at least for me). Also each event is composed of the `name` and `desc`. I did not find a way to associate the adjacent elements in the desired structure using css selectors. I figured I would need a custom subroutine to return to do that associations of the elements. What I would like to retrieve is something similar to the following :

```
[
 'February 20, 2014' => [
     {
     'name' => 'Name 1',
     'desc' => 'Desc 1'
     }
 ],
 'February 21, 2014' => [
     {
     'name' => 'Name 2',
     'desc' => 'Desc 2'
     },
     {
     'name' => 'Name 3',
     'desc' => 'Desc 3'
     }
 ],
 'February 22, 2014' => [
     {
     'name' => 'Name 4',
     'desc' => 'Desc 4'
     }
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better served by getting the data first, and then processing these after the scraper.  So...:

```
my $scraper = scraper {
  process ".when", "dates[]" => "TEXT";
  process ".name", "names[]" => "TEXT";
  process ".desc", "desc[]" => "TEXT";
};

my $result = $scraper->scrape($html);

# Here you would start processing these

my @dates = @{ $result->{dates} };
my @names = @{ $result->{names} };
my @info = @{ $result->{desc} };
my %events;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @dates; $i++ ) {
  my $date = $dates[$i];
  my $name = $names[$i];
  my $info = $info[$i];
  if ( exists $events{$date} ) {
    push @{ $events{$date} }, { 'name' => $name, 'desc' => $info };
  }
  else {
    $events{$date} = [{ 'name' => $name, 'desc' => $info}];
  }
}
```

%events would have the data you need.  This is all assuming you still need this, and each event date has a name and description after it.  Also, I haven't tested this.